# Converting mouse point

Tags: c#, math

I have two image, imageA = 800x600 size and the other imageB = 1440x900. If I for example click in the imageA at 50x50 coordinates, how can I convert it the value of imageB with correct location?

Comment: Is the latter a distorted version of the former? What is the rule for coordinates transformation between them?

Answer (score 0):

```
newX = x * 1440 / 800;
newY = y * 900 / 600;
```

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the difference ratios (newX/oldX), then multiply. In short for your practical example:

```
int newX = (50*1440)/800;
int newX = (50*900)/600);
```

Note that I have switched the calculation to explicitly multiply first for practical reasons, otherwise you'd have to cast to float in between to avoid unintended rounding.

Answer (score 0):

This code treats integer coordinates as the center of the pixel, and it works on the edges too.

```
x2 = round((x + 0.5) * 1440.0 / 800.0);
y2 = round((y + 0.5) * 900.0 / 600.0);
```

**Edit**: this assumes (0,0) is your corner not (1,1). That is usually the case.

Comment: `round(x + 0.5)` <--- what's the point for this? And what is `round`?

Comment: `round` is http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/ form the standard C library, and I forgot a bracket there. I will correct it.

Comment: `C(++) !======== C#` (the operator I just used means "very not equals to")

Comment: I don't know the C# library by heart. I assume it has a `round` function. If I have to guess I'd say it's something like `Math.round` or `Integer.round`. But it does the same thing in every language it rounds floats to whole numbers.

Comment: well, it makes sense to not answer the questions about languages you're not competent in then. Just my humble opinion.

Comment: Don't let the C# tag fool you, it's not a C# question. It's simply algorithmic.

Comment: to be precise - it's not about algorithms either, it's about primary school arithmetic :-)